# Библиотека для визуализации графа на с++

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, graph

стоит задача визуализировать граф как на изображении ниже. Есть код на с++, описывающий графы данного вида. Есть ли какие-то бибилиотеки для плюсов, позволяющие изобразить данного вида графы?

[image: Пример графа]

Comment: Dot например. Посмотрите исходники Doxygen'а там много примеров чего и как использовать для графов, С++ API.

Comment: Только dot это не библиотека, а формат graphviz.

Comment: Собвственно graphviz http://www.graphviz.org/download/

Comment: @VTT, это ещё и одноимённая утилита в составе graphviz: [man dot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dot).

Answer (score -1):

Один из вариантов, при помощи библиотеки FLTK (Fast Light Tool Kit). Много информации можно найти в книге Бьерна Страуструпа «Принципы и практика использования C++», там рассказывается про GUI и программирование графики. 
Можно посмотреть в сторону класса описанный в этой книге - OpenPolyline.
Сам пользовался этой книжкой для Практических задач в университете. 
Надеюсь поможет.